# Sum by distinct column value in R

Tags: r, sum, unique, data.table

I have a very large dataframe in R and would like to sum two columns for every distinct value in other columns, for example say we had data of a dataframe of transactions in various shops over a day as follows

```
shop <- data.frame('shop_id' = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3), 
  'shop_name' = c('Shop A', 'Shop A', 'Shop A', 'Shop B', 'Shop C', 'Shop C'), 
  'city' = c('London', 'London', 'London', 'Cardiff', 'Dublin', 'Dublin'), 
  'sale' = c(12, 5, 9, 15, 10, 18), 
  'profit' = c(3, 1, 3, 6, 5, 9))
```

which is:

```
shop_id  shop_name    city      sale profit
   1     Shop A       London    12   3
   1     Shop A       London    5    1
   1     Shop A       London    9    3
   2     Shop B       Cardiff   15   6
   3     Shop C       Dublin    10   5
   3     Shop C       Dublin    18   9
```

And I'd want to sum the sale and profit for each shop to give:

```
shop_id  shop_name    city      sale profit
   1     Shop A       London    26   7
   2     Shop B       Cardiff   15   6
   3     Shop C       Dublin    28   14
```

I am currently using the following code to do this:

```
 shop_day <-ddply(shop, "shop_id", transform, sale=sum(sale), profit=sum(profit))
 shop_day <- subset(shop_day, !duplicated(shop_id))
```

which works absolutely fine, but as I said my dataframe is large (140,000 rows, 37 columns and nearly 100,000 unique rows which I want to sum) and my code takes ages to run and then eventually says it has run out of memory.

Does anyone know of the most efficient way to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ...I feel a `data.table` answer coming...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the neatest way to do this is in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
shop %>% 
  group_by(shop_id, shop_name, city) %>% 
  summarise_all(sum)
```

Answer (score 18):

** Obligatory Data Table answer **

```
> library(data.table)
data.table 1.8.0  For help type: help("data.table")
> shop.dt <- data.table(shop)
> shop.dt[,list(sale=sum(sale), profit=sum(profit)), by='shop_id']
     shop_id sale profit
[1,]       1   26      7
[2,]       2   15      6
[3,]       3   28     14
>
```

Which sounds fine and good until things get bigger...

```
shop <- data.frame(shop_id = letters[1:10], profit=rnorm(1e7), sale=rnorm(1e7))
shop.dt <- data.table(shop)

> system.time(ddply(shop, .(shop_id), summarise, sale=sum(sale), profit=sum(profit)))
   user  system elapsed 
  4.156   1.324   5.514 
> system.time(shop.dt[,list(sale=sum(sale), profit=sum(profit)), by='shop_id'])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.728   0.108   0.840 
>
```

You get additional speed increases if you create the data.table with a key:

```
shop.dt <- data.table(shop, key='shop_id')

> system.time(shop.dt[,list(sale=sum(sale), profit=sum(profit)), by='shop_id'])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.252   0.084   0.336 
>
```

Comment: Note that Justin is using `summarise` instead `transform` in his `ddply` call; that change is probably enough to get your code working without the memory error, though other solutions are certainly faster.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks! I left that explanation since there was an earlier answer that explained it.  However that was since deleted!

Comment: Thanks Justin, much quicker. Another quick question, is there a way of keeping the other columns (e.g. shop_name, city) in the final data table? I can join back on the initial dataframe to get this but would be neater if there was a way to do this within the initial query.

Comment: Also is there any knock on effects from having my data frame now stored as a data table later on? does it perform any differently for any particular queries? Thanks

Comment: There can be some surprises later on, but you can always use `as.data.frame` to drop the data table attribute.  As far as keeping the original columns, you sure can.  you can merge them or add them to the `list()` with `unique(shop_name)`.  take a look at `?merge.data.table` for more info on the merge.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to use base R to speed up operations like this:

```
idx <- split(1:nrow(shop), shop$shop_id)
a2 <- data.frame(shop_id=sapply(idx, function(i) shop$shop_id[i[1]]),
                 sale=sapply(idx, function(i) sum(shop$sale[i])), 
                 profit=sapply(idx, function(i) sum(shop$profit[i])) )
```

Time reduces to 0.75 sec vs 5.70 sec for the ddply summarise version on my system.

Comment: If I have many columns like sale and profit in above example which I want to sum, is it possible to call a single function to combine third and fourth line in above code into a single line.

Comment: Not really using this exact method, but there are ways of doing that. Start a new question with a minimally reproducible example and you'll get plenty of suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case, if you have long list of columns,
use summarize_if()

#### Summarizes all columns if data type is int

```
library(dplyr)
shop %>% 
  group_by(shop_id, shop_name, city) %>% 
  summarise_if(is.integer, sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry my english is not very good.

I have a data like this

group    X
A        2
A        1
C        1
B        5
A        2
C        1
C        2
B        5
B        5

I want to have a table who gives me

The sum of unique values by group like this:

group     X

A         3

B         5

C         3

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33816148)